# Creating a regression testing sprint in agile?

Tags: agile, regression-testing

I am in a team which we are delivering a product right now. We are preparing for `regression sprint` it will be the next sprint. In this sprint `testers` will have to test the whole application to ensure that the application in a stable state.

The problem is in development team actually we finished the queue of tasks that is needed for the current release, and we have a large queue of tasks but in another release.

I can think of two options to solve this issue

1. Doing a regression with some of testing team and let the other testing team join the development team to work in the next release
2. Dedicate a sprint to regression & bug fixing.

**Hint:** we have limited resources in testing so we can't offer a team for testing the regression

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a 'regression testing sprint'. It is a contradiction in terms, as a sprint includes everything that is necessary to deliver a potentially shippable increment of software.

In Scrum we do development, testing (including regression testing) within a time box that we call a sprint. We do this because:

- We want to deliver working software every sprint
- We want to give a true reflection of progress

When you save up the regression testing you are giving a false impression of progress. It may appear that certain functionality has been completed, but really until it has been regression tested there is no way to know how much work remains (e.g. there may be regression bugs to fix).

It is interesting that you say you have limited testing resources. I suspect what you mean by this is that you have limited people who have the label of 'tester'. A developer can do regression testing. They may even write automated regression tests, a particularly powerful approach when doing agile development.

In your current situation I would suggest you have sprint dedicated to finishing off the outstanding work. That means regression testing and bug fixing. If the developers don't have bugs to fix they should help out with the regression testing (either manually or by writing automated regression tests).

For the future try not to let testing get out of synch with development. Aim to finish every sprint with each story in a state of 'done' that includes regression testing and any other work that is necessary for it to be ready for a production release.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to revisit your dev process so in the future

- through automation of various tests (done by developers)
- and/or by adding some time in sprint x+1 to fix the bugs found in sprint x
- and/or by making smaller stories that can be implemented and validated in a single sprint (see the size of the sprint)
- and/or a shift in culture if dev and qa are seen as different teams

you gradually come to avoid a scenario like your current one.
Assumption: you are not maintaining a huge legacy system (cobol) where a hardening sprint , or more, might make sense.

for the moment option 2 looks like the best compromise, assuming your devs will help the testing and testers will not find so many bugs that you will need a new sprint for bug fixing a new regression, etc :).